# SQL: How to aggregate multiple rows according to commutable columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, relational-database

Table MESSAGES (example of log messages from one user to the other):

```
| id | from_user_id | to_user_id | message_body |
|  1 |       7      |     10     |      ...     |
|  2 |       3      |      1     |      ...     |
|  3 |      95      |     14     |      ...     |
|  4 |      95      |      3     |      ...     |
|  5 |       1      |      3     |      ...     |
|  6 |       1      |      3     |      ...     |
|  7 |      10      |      7     |      ...     |
|  8 |       3      |     95     |      ...     |
...
```

I would like to COUNT (or execute any other aggregate function) how many users' **conversation** I have in this table.
A conversation is defined as a message ***from A to B** OR **from B to A***. Notice that the order doesn't count as *the ids are commutable one to each other*.

So, the result I would like to get is:

Table CONVERSATIONS:

```
| id | user_id_1 | user_id_2 | messages_count |
|  1 |     7     |     10    |       2        |
|  2 |     3     |      1    |       3        |
|  3 |    95     |     14    |       1        |
|  4 |    95     |      3    |       2        |
...
```

**How would I be able to do this using a SQL Query?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `least` and `greatest`:

```
select least(from_user_id, to_user_id) user_id_1,
       greatest(from_user_id, to_user_id) user_id_2,
       count(*)
from messages
group by 1, 2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7255b/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user1,
       user2,
       COUNT(*) as messageCount
FROM
(
  SELECT from_user_id as user1, 
         to_user_id as user2
  FROM T
  WHERE from_user_id<= to_user_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT to_user_id as user1,
         from_user_id as user2
  FROM T
  WHERE from_user_id> to_user_id
) as T1
GROUP BY user1,user2
```

<kbd>[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48beb/1)</kbd>